# Issue importing CodeCoverage to SonarQube using Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: c#, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, code-coverage

Cannot upload the CodeCoverage result to SonarQube. The Unit Tests appear (along the static analysis result) but codecoverage remains 0%

The Unit Testing is made in Jenkins and is successful according to the Jenkins Console but no coveragexml file is generated…

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages{
    stage('Checkout'){
      agent {
        label 'Miguel'
      }
      steps {
        checkout scm
      }
    }

stage('Static Analysis'){
  agent {
    label 'Miguel'
  }
  steps {
    script {
      echo "Starting Static Analysis Stage"
      def msbuild = tool name: 'MSBuildMiguel', type: 'hudson.plugins.msbuild.MsBuildInstallation'
      def sonarHome = tool 'MSBuildSonarScannerMiguel'
      def vstest = tool 'vstestMiguel'
      def codecoverage = tool 'codecoverageMiguel'
      withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube'){
        bat """
          ${sonarHome}/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:com.SecurityUtilities /n:TTSecurity /v:1.0 /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=**/*.trx /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=**/*.coveragexml
          ${msbuild} TTSecurity.sln /t:Rebuild
          ${vstest} /Logger:trx "TTSecurityTests\\bin\\Release\\TTSecurityTests.dll" 

          ${codecoverage} analyze /output:d:**.coveragexml  d:**.coverage

          ${sonarHome}/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

The Unit Testing is done:

Starting test execution, please wait...
(...)
Results File: C:\Users\FNM1AV\Desktop\JenkinsSlave\workspace\Security_Utilities_master\TestResults\FNM1AV_PT-N01504_2019-09-10_22_47_24.trx

Test Run Successful.
Total tests: 18
     Passed: 18
 Total time: 1.8712 Seconds

The Jenkins Console shows:

"WARN: Could not find any coverage report file matching the pattern '**/*.coveragexml'."